# Can't get Drag and Drop to work with html5/javascript

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop

So I have only been learning html/css/javascript for a few months now and I can't seem to get drag and drop to work with html5/javascript. I'm not actually making a website or anything I'm just trying to learn and I have got html elements to become draggable with jQuery I just can't seem to get it to work with html5/javascript.

My html code is as followed:

```
<DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <body>
            <img id="steam" src="http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/Steam_Logo.png" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" />
            <div id="div1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowdrop(event)"></div>
        </body>
    </html>
```

My css code is as followed:

```
#div1 {
width:350px;
height:350px;
border:2px solid #AA560B;
}
```

My javascript is as followed:

```
window.onload = function(){
    function allowDrop(ev){
        ev.preventDefault();
    }
    function drag(ev){
        ev.dataTransfer.setData("text",ev.target.id);
    }
    function drop(ev){
        ev.preventDefault();
        var data=ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
        ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
    }            
}
```

I'm not entirely sure what I'm doing wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: can you see any Javascript errors in your developer console?

Comment: Just that allowdrop event was not defined but I solved the issue. Thank you for your response.

Answer (score 4):

You have a typo in your HTML, your function in HTML is not camelCase like in Javascript.

This line:

```
<div id="div1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
```

Change allowdrop to allowDrop.

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/U55rc/

You now have a problem with positioning because the box will automatically snap to top without the Steam logo there, but that's another problem entirely.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Angular and I had to include the drag and drop functions in my  tag inside index.html. This helped me.

```
<script>
  function allowDrop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
  }
  function drag(ev) {
    ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
  }
  function drop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
    ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
  }
</script>
```